# Array Adapter ```getItem(position)``` returning null first time (but works fine on next time check)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I have created a **dropdown** using a custom layout and `AutoCompleteTextView`.
On submit button click I am checking if the user selected any items or not from that dropdown.

But even if an item is selected, a validation error is occurring on the validation check for the first time instead of no error.

The below code is for setting up my dropdown.

```
//Ambulance Types Dropdown Data
            ambulanceTypes = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ambulance_types);
            ambulanceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.dropdown_item, ambulanceTypes);
            ambulanceDropdown = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            ambulanceDropdown.setAdapter(ambulanceAdapter);
```

I created a **String** variable to get the selected value in it as shown in the code below.

```
String ambulanceTypesValue;
ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> ambulanceTypesValue = ambulanceAdapter.getItem(position));
```

Below is the validation method I am calling on button click.

```
private boolean checkAmbulanceTypes() {
        ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> ambulanceTypesValue = ambulanceAdapter.getItem(position));
        if (ambulanceTypesValue == null) {
            ambulanceDropdown.requestFocus();
            ambulanceDropdown.setError("Please select an ambulance.");
            return false;
        } else {
            ambulanceDropdown.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding this code line repeatedly into the `onResume()` method.

```
ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> ambulanceTypesValue = ambulanceAdapter.getItem(position));
```

**DETAILS:** That line code is getting selected value from the dropdown and I repeated that line code in the onResume() method to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok look my friend you write little information, but I will try to help you.

**First**:
Remove ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener from your funcation and pass string as a parameter

```html
private boolean checkAmbulanceTypes(String Types) {
        if (Types == null) {
            ambulanceDropdown.requestFocus();
            ambulanceDropdown.setError("Please select an ambulance.");
            return false;
        } else {
            ambulanceDropdown.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Second**:

```html
String ambulanceTypesValue;
ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> ambulanceTypesValue = ambulanceAdapter.getItem(position));
```

Remove this String from code above and in ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener put your funcation to be your code

```html
    ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> checkAmbulanceTypes(ambulanceAdapter.getItem(position)));
```

now your adapter will work fine and you will get a boolean value in setOnItemClickListener.

**Note**:
if you prefer use String ambulanceTypesValue to get the item which uses just change to

```html
 String ambulanceTypesValue;
    ambulanceDropdown.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> ambulanceTypesValue = ambulanceAdapter.getItem(position);
    );
    
    /*and on click button*/
    
    onclick{
    checkAmbulanceTypes(ambulanceTypesValue);
    ambulanceTypesValue=null;/*to clear value*/
    }
```